# Print 3 decimals in TikZ Without using standard form

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to do a ruler display from 0 to 1 using 3 decimal numbers. So I would like the ruler to look something like this:

0.000   0.001   0.002   0.003 ..... 0.010   0.011

An so on.

Since this would be to loong to fit in 1 page, I plan to split it in several pages and I use this piece of code for the first page

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]

\draw[ultra thick,color=black] (0,0) -- (26,0);
\foreach \x[evaluate=\x as \text using \x*0.001] in {0,1,2,3,...,40}{
    \draw[shift={(\x*0.65,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[yshift = -20pt,rotate = 270] { 
         \pgfmathparse{\x*0.001}\pgfmathprintnumberto[precision=1] {\pgfmathresult}{\pgfmathresult} \pgfmathresult };
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

After runing this code I get the following output

[image]

Is it posible to get the number not in standard form but a shown in the written example?

Is it posible to make the loop more simple and not use evaluate and just do something like:

```
\draw[shift={(\x*0.65,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[yshift = -20pt,rotate = 270] { \x*0.001 };
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you have that `\pgfmathparse` stuff when you're already using `evaluate`. Just use `\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=3]{\text}` in the `node` text. `fixed` disables the scientific notation. Use `\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3]{\text}` to get `0.000` instead of `0.0`.

You cannot use `\x*0.001` in the node text directly, as that is not parsed as a number, it is just text. You could say `node[...]{\pgfmathparse{\x*0.001}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}};`, but then I'd say `evaluate` is cleaner.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round]
\draw[ultra thick,color=black] (0,0) -- (26,0);
\foreach \x[evaluate=\x as \text using \x*0.001] in {0,...,40}{
    \draw (\x*0.65,2pt) -- ++(0,-4pt)
       node[below=3pt,anchor=west,align=left,rotate = 270] 
          {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3]{\text}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not know exactly how pgf works so I try to find patches to my problems and sometimes I do silly things.

Is it posible to sho 3 decimal on 0 (so 0.000) and rest of decimals that woul end in 0 or 00
i.e.
0.100
0.110

and so on?

Thanks

Comment: @xiscorompa Sorry, didn't see the edit on your comment, only the original one. Use `fixed,fixed zerofill` instead of just `fixed`, see updated answer.