# Decimal places in fixed point arithmetic with negative numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmath

I have the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{fp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}


\begin{document}

\tikzset{fixed point arithmetic}
\tikzmath{
    real \x; real \y;
    %
    \x=-1.3754;
    \y = \fpeval{round(\x*5.56,3)};
}

\tikzset{fixed point arithmetic}
\tikzmath{
    real \z; real \w;
    %
    \z=1.3754;
    \w = \fpeval{round(\z*5.56,3)};
}


\vspace{3cm}

O valor de $x$ é: \fpeval{round(\x,3)} \\ 
O valor de $y$ é: \y \\


O valor de $z$ é: \fpeval{round(\z,3)} \\ 
O valor de $w$ é: \w \\

\end{document}
```

whose output is the following:

[image]

When I operate negative numbers in `tikzmath`, the decimal places of the result is incontrolable. However when the calculation deal with positive real numbers, I set the decimal places with `\fpeval{round(x,3)}` (to three decimal places) and I can to control the precision.
My question is how can I fix this? Why `fixed point arithmetic` is noisy with negative numbers? I would to set the decimal places in the `tikzmath` code space, not in the text.
Many thanks!

Comment: Replace last line with `O valor de $y$ é: \fpeval{round(\y,3)}` works. No idea why

Comment: That having said, coming from other programming languages, use `round()` to print number to X decimal places feel absolutely like the wrong way.

Comment: I want to control the decimal places in the tikzmath code, not in the last LINE.

Comment: Then you already controlled it. `-7.647 == -7.6470000000000`. What you want is to *print* the number to 3 decimal places.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350446/print-3-decimals-in-tikz-without-using-standard-form suggests `pgfmathprintnumber`, which works in this case.

Comment: Not controlled in the ```tikzmath``` mode when the number is negative. When Is positive the command ```round``` works. Try!

Comment: It does work in that the resulting value is correct. I don't think there's anything in the documentation that states that the result is guaranteed to be stored in the minimal form.

Comment: Alternatively `siunitx` can be used too. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599426/xfp-zerofill-at-fpeval

Comment: Not solved yet......

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding something. Either you only care only about the *value* of the numbers; in that case the produced value and the expected value is exactly equal; or you care about how it looks like in text, then use the text formatting commands.

Comment: I am concerned about the appearance and value of the result. The only thing I don't understand is because Tikz puts too many zeros when the calculation involves negative numbers and I can't get those zeros inside the tikzmath environment

Comment: If you are concerned about the appearance then use the text formatting command? ■ While the internal storage of the value is inconsistent; it's not a bug because the value is correct; nevertheless just wait a bit and see if the TikZ developers are interested in changing the behavior (perhaps some efficiency improvement or something).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132341/discussion-between-angelo-aliano-filho-and-user202729).

Answer (score 1):

Use the numprint package. the "autolanguage" option adjusts the unit and thousand separators according to the babel package option, in this case Brazilian Portuguese.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{article}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{fp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{fixed point arithmetic}
\tikzmath{
    real \x; real \y;
    %
    \x=-1.3754;
    \y = \fpeval{round(\x*5.56,3)};
}

\tikzset{fixed point arithmetic}
\tikzmath{
    real \z; real \w;
    %
    \z=1.3754;
    \w = \fpeval{round(\z*5.56,3)};
}

\vspace{3cm}

\nprounddigits{3}
O valor de $x$ é: \numprint{\x}  \\
O valor de $y$ é: \numprint{\y} \\

\nprounddigits{4}
O valor de $z$ é: \numprint{\z} \\
O valor de $w$ é: \numprint{\w} \\

\end{document}
```

[image]